# Disk let free to rotate

Tags: angular-momentum, torque, moment-of-inertia, rigid-body-dynamics

A rigid body moving with no constraints, in particular rotating, will rotate necessarily about a **principal axis of inertia**.

I thought that the reason of this is that otherwise, the angular momentum $\vec{L}$ would not be parallel to the angular velocity $\vec{\omega}$, hence it would follow a precession motion and that would imply the presence of a torque, which is not present if the body is let free.

But then I came up with this example.

A disk rotates about an axis $\hat{c}$, which is not parallel to a principal axis of inertia. The supports exert the torque necessary for this rotation. At $t_0$  the supports break. The angular momentum vector $\vec{L(t_0)}$ of the disk cannot change anymore, but how will the disk rotate? (In the picture there is the disk before and after supports break).

[image: The disk before and after supports break]

On textbook it is stated that disk starts rotating about its principal axis of inertia $\hat{u}$ passing through its center of mass with angular velocity $\vec{\omega_R}$ but it also follows a precession motion about the (constant) angular momentum vector, with angular velocity $\vec{\omega_P}$.

Why does this happen? **A variation of $\vec{\omega}$ (in direction) means an angular acceleration, which in turns imply the presence of a torque**. But there is no torque here, the disk is free.

On the other hand of course $\vec{L}$ cannot change, and it is not parallel to a principal axis of inertia.

So how can $\vec{\omega}$ change? And does a rigid body always rotate about a principal axis of inertia, no matter if the angular momentum is parallel to it or not?

Comment: Related: [What causes precession or nutation in a spinning object?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/53153/what-causes-precession-or-nutation-in-a-spinning-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A rigid body moving with no constraints, in particular rotating, will rotate necessarily about a principal axis of inertia.
>
> I thought that the reason of this is that otherwise, the angular momentum $\vec L$ would not be parallel to the angular velocity $\vec\omega$, hence it would follow a precession motion and that would imply the presence of a torque, which is not present if the body is let free.

This is incorrect. A rigid body rotating in torque-free conditions can have any angular momentum. A [torque-free precession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precession#Torque-free) results if this angular momentum happens to not be aligned with one of the principal axes.

Answer (score 0):

The axis of rotation changing even when there is no applied torque is an effect which is possible in 3-dimensions but not in 2-dimensions.

The angular momentum about an axis $\vec L$ is given by $\vec L = I \vec \omega$ where $I$ is the moment of inertia about the axis and $\vec \omega$  is the angular velocity about the axis.

If you are observing an asymmetric body, like the disc, with total angular momentum $\vec L$ then if there are no forces (and hence no torques) acting on the body the total angular momentum of the body is constant.

In a frame of reference fixed relative to the centre of mass of the body the sum of the x, y and z components of the angular momentum will be constant.

$\vec L = \vec L_x + \vec L_y +\vec L_z$.

Because the body is asymmetric as it rotates relative to the frame of reference its moment of inertia about an axis will change eg from $I_x$ to $I_x^\prime$ and this in turn will change the angular velocity about that axis from $\omega_x$ to $\omega_x^\prime$ subject to the constraint  that the angular momentum in the x-direction, $L_x = I_x \omega_x$ to $I_x^ \prime \omega_x^\prime$, stays constant.

This means that what you observe as the rotation of the object is the initial angular velocity, $\vec \omega = \vec \omega_x + \vec \omega_y +\vec \omega_z$, changing to a new angular velocity, $\vec \omega^\prime = \vec \omega_x^\prime + \vec \omega_y^\prime +\vec \omega_z^\prime$.
So you observe a change in the direction of the axis of rotation although the total angular momentum has not changed.

A full analysis requires one to keep the total kinetic energy of the body, $\frac{1}{2}I \omega^2$, constant.

See [Poinsot's_ellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poinsot's_ellipsoid) and the references listed in the article although the wonderful "Poinsot construction in stereo 3D simulation" seems no longer to be available.